# Maven testResource filtering is not working in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml, maven-resources-plugin

I am using testResource to filter data in pom.xml. But instead of printing the data, I am getting back the variable itself as shown in the code. Looks resource filtering is not happening. Can someone please advise me what am I doing wrong here and how to correct it.

pom.xml

```
<project 

  <properties>
    <local.buildNumber>${local.bhuildNumber}</local.buildNumber>
  </properties>

  <dependencies></dependencies

  <build>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/src/test/java/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

        <plugins></plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

global.properties

```
local.buildNumber=${local.buildNumber}
```

A.java

```
public void finish() throws IOException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/resources/global.properties");
        prop.load(fileInput);
        String value = prop.getProperty("local.buildNumber");

        //it prints ${local.buildNumber} though I am expecting 40
        System.out.println(value); }
```

Project structure:

```
Project
-src
--main
----java
--test
----java
----resources
------global.properties
--pom.xml
--target/
```

Comment: First you directory layout looks a bit strange..`src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources` and `src/test/java` and `src/main/java` are the correct locations.furthermore the properties file should be put into `src/test/resources` in case you want to have it only for testing. Furthermore don't access the source location go via `getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/global.properties")`...

Comment: @khmarbaise project structure updated, but yes I will take out the resource folder from java package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config

```
<build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
```

And for load file try working with the ClassLoader class:

```java
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("global.properties").getFile());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: thanks for answering. There is one disadvantage to this, with each mvn call I have to pass a variable as well. Example, mvn clean -Dlocal.buildNumber=40  or   mvn test -Dlocal.buildNumber=40 If I don't pass a variable with each command it throws NullPointerException. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: yes it is working now but created another issue i just mentioned above

Comment: You can set a default value via the default profile ```xml <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Default</id>
    
            <activation>
             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            -
            <properties>
                <local.buildnumber>1</local.buildnumber>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>```